# vb.net lambda too many arguments

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I'm new to VB.net and am currently writing some codesamples for common constructs (that wont make any sense) that I will probably need in an upcoming project. I have a class with lambda expressions as properties, which looks like this:

```
Namespace SampleClasses
    Public Class Lambdas
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property AddFromZeroUpTo As Func(Of Integer, Integer)
            Get
                Return Function(upTo As Integer) Enumerable.Range(0, upTo + 1).Sum()
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property ShowMessageBox As Action(Of String)
            Get
                Return Function(text As String) MessageBox.Show(text)
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now when I try to call those lambdas some lines work, some wont, and I dont really get why.

```
SampleClasses.Lambdas.ShowMessageBox()(SampleClasses.Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8)) 'works
SampleClasses.Lambdas.ShowMessageBox(SampleClasses.Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8)) 'wont work
SampleClasses.Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8) 'wont work
SampleClasses.Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo()(8) 'works
Dim msg = SampleClasses.Lambdas.ShowMessageBox
msg(SampleClasses.Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8)) 'works
```

I'm really stumped at this behaviour and have no clue why this behaves this way, thanks for any suggestions what to look for or explanations.

Comment: In VB.NET (unlike C#), properties can have arguments.  So the syntax is ambiguous, when you use AddFromZeroUpTo(8) then the compiler thinks that you are trying to pass 8 to the property getter.  You have to resolve the ambiguity by using ()(8), now the compiler is suitably convinced you meant to pass 8 to the delegate.  Well, clean syntax out of the window here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ShowMessageBox and AddFromZeroUpTo are properties. And they are defined to be ReadOnly and to return a delegate of some sort.
So you get the value of these properties and Invoke the delegates returned.
You can't pass anything to these properties like they were methods.

If you add the Invoke method implicit in your calls you get

```
' Get the delegate returned and invoke it
Lambdas.ShowMessageBox.Invoke(Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8)) 

' Doesn't make sense. ShowMessageBox is a read only property
'Lambdas.ShowMessageBox(Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8)) 'wont work

' Use the delegate returned from AddFromZeroUp
Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo.Invoke(8) 

' That's the same as above with the Invoke omitted
Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo()(8) 

' First calls the delegate returned by 
' AddFromZeroUpTo and with the return value calls the delegate returned
' by ShowMessageBox
Dim msg = Lambdas.ShowMessageBox
msg(Lambdas.AddFromZeroUpTo(8))
```

Notice that this code works only if you have Option Strict turned Off on your project. A very unwise move from many points of view.